# For entire function $|f(z)| \leq |z|^{1.5}$, how to use Liouville's theorem.

Tags: complex-analysis

I am  considering the following problem :

Let $f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be an entire function. Assume $|f(z)|\leq |z|^{1.5}$ and apply Taylor's theorem or Liouville's theorem (if you can) to say any properties of $f$.

I wanna use Liouville's theorem for $g(z):=\frac{f(z)}{z^{1.5}}$. But singularity of $g$ at $z=0$ gives me difficulties.

Can we conclude that $f(z)=Cz^{1.5} $?

If not, what can we say by applying Talyor or Liouville's theorem for the $f$?

Answer (score 2):

From $|f(z)|\le |z|^{3/2}$ we infer $f(0)=0$, hence $f(z)=zg(z)$ for some entire $g$. Then  $|g(z)|\le |z|^{1/2}$ and hence $g(0)=0$, $g(z)=zh(z)$ for some entire $h$. Then for $|z|\ge r$, we have $|h(z)|=|z^{-2}f(z)|\le |z|^{-1/2}\le r^{-1/2}$ and conclude that $h$ is bounded, hence constant. As $r$ was arbitrary, that constant must be $0$ and ultimately $f(z)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is entire, we have the following Taylor expansion of $f$:
$$f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\,\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}\,z^k\text{ for every }z\in\mathbb{C}\,.$$
Let $R>0$ be arbitrary.  From [Cauchy's Estimate for Derivatives](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~stephentu/blog/complex-analysis/2017/09/16/cauchy-estimate-derivative.html), we see that 
$$\big|f^{(k)}(0)\big|\leq \frac{k!}{R^k}\,R^{\frac{3}{2}}=\frac{k!}{R^{k-\frac{3}{2}}}$$
for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ and for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $|z|=R$.  If $k\geq 2$, then by letting $R\to\infty$, we obtain $f^{(k)}(0)=0$.  That is, $f$ is a linear polynomial.

Because $\big|f(0)\big|\leq 0^{\frac32}=0$, we get $f(0)=0$.  Hence, there exists a constant $a\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $f(z)=az$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$.  Finally, to have
$$|a|\,|z|=\big|f(z)\big|\leq |z|^{\frac{3}{2}}\text{ for all }z\in\mathbb{C}\,,$$
we must have
$$|a|\leq |z|^{\frac12}\text{ for every }z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}\,.$$
By letting $z\to 0$, we see that $a=0$.  Hence, the only function that satisfies the requirement is the zero function $f\equiv 0$.

**Remark.**  If the problem instead states that $f(z)\leq |z|^{\frac32}$ for *all sufficiently large* complex numbers $z$, then the answer is different.  Any linear function $f$ satisfies this requirement.  Let $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$ be such that $f(z)=az+b$ for every $z\in\mathbb{C}$.  If $a=0$, then $\big|f(z)\big|\leq |z|^{\frac{3}{2}}$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $|z|\geq |b|^{\frac{2}{3}}$.  If $a\neq 0$, then $\big|f(z)\big|\leq |z|^{\frac32}$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $|z|\geq \max\left\{4\,|a|^2,\dfrac{|b|}{|a|}\right\}$.

---

More generally, if $\alpha,\beta\geq 0$ and $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is an entire function such that $\big|f(z)\big|\leq \alpha\,|z|^\beta$ for *every sufficiently large* $z\in\mathbb{C}$, then $f$ is a polynomial of degree at most $\lfloor \beta\rfloor$.  If $\beta$ is not an integer, then any polynomial function $f$ of degree at most $\lfloor\beta\rfloor$ satisfies the condition.  If $\beta\in\mathbb{Z}$, then any polynomial function $f$ of degree less than $\beta$ satisfies the condition, and any polynomial function $f$ of the form $f(z)=\gamma\,z^\beta+g(z)$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ also works, where $g$ is a polynomial of degree less than $\beta$ and $\gamma\in\mathbb{C}$ satisfies $|\gamma|<\alpha$.  If $\beta\in\mathbb{Z}$, then any polynomial function $f$ of the form $f(z)=\gamma\,z^\beta+g(z)$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ fails, where $g$ is a polynomial of degree less than $\beta$ and $\gamma\in\mathbb{C}$ satisfies $|\gamma|>\alpha$, but for $|\gamma|=\alpha$, the only possibility is $f(z)=\gamma\,z^\beta$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$, and this can be proven via the lemma below (which is a consequence of the [Open Mapping Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(complex_analysis))).

> **Lemma.**  Let $p:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ be a nonconstant polynomial function such that $p(0)=0$.  Then, for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists a complex number $z$ such that $|z|<\epsilon$ and $p(z)$ is a positive real number.

If we consider $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ such that $\big|f(z)\big|\leq \alpha\,|z|^\beta$ for ***all*** $z\in\mathbb{C}$ instead, then the answer is $f\equiv 0$ for noninteger values of $\beta$.  If $\beta\in\mathbb{Z}$, then $f(z)=\gamma\,z^\beta$ for some $\gamma\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $|\gamma|\leq \alpha$.

Comment: Thank you for your kind explanation.

Answer (score 0):

we have that $|f(z)| \leq |z|^{1.5}$ for all $z$. For $z = 0$, this gives us that $|f(0)| \leq 0$, and so $f(0) = 0$. There is thus an analytic function $g$ such that $f(z) = z g(z)$ for all $z$.

We thus have that $|z| |g(z)| \leq |z|^{1.5}$ for all $z$, and so $|g(z)| \leq |z|^{0.5}$ for all $z$. As before, this implies that $g(0) = 0$, and so there is an analytic function $h$ such that $g(z) = z h(z)$ for all $z$.

We find that $|h(z)| \leq |z|^{-0.5}$ for all $z$. Since $|h|$ is continuous, it attains a maximum value on the unit disk $|z| \leq 1$. Thus there is some constant $M$ such that $|h(z)| \leq M$ for all $z$ such that $|z| \leq 1$. For $|z| > 1$, we have that $|h(z)| \leq |z|^{-0.5} < 1$. We thus have that $|h(z)| \leq \max\{1, M\}$ for all $z$. We thus have that $h$ is bounded, and hence $h$ is a constant.

We find that there is a constant $C$ such that $f(z) = Cz^2$ for all $z$. But we require that $|C| |z|^2 = |f(z)| \leq |z|^{1.5}$, and hence $|C| \leq |z|^{-0.5}$ for all $z$. This implies that $C = 0$, and so we have that $f$ is identically $0$.

Comment: Very Nice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$
g(z)=\frac{f(z)-f(0)-z\,f'(0)}{z^2}
$$
is entire and bounded since $|f(z)|\le|z|^{1.5}$. Furthermore, $g(z)\to0$ as $|z|\to\infty$.

Thus, $f(z)=f(0)+z\,f'(0)$. The condition that $|f(z)|\le|z|^{1.5}$ implies that $f(z)=0$.